# ConnectionRequest is not working in iOS

Tags: codenameone

I've a year & a half old app to update. It was written in statemachine. Now I added a few things but the connectionRequest doesn't seem to work in iOS (which was built for iOS debug). I built it in android and it works very well.

```
 public void connectionForLogin(String username, String password) {
    ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> response = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
            if (response != null) {
                for (Map<String, Object> element : response) {
                    success = (String) element.get("login");
                    msg = (String) element.get("msg");

                    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> userInfoArray = (ArrayList) element.get("user_info");
                    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("userInfo", userInfoArray);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            super.postResponse(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException err) {
        }
    };
    cr.setPost(true);
    cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    cr.setTimeout(30000);
    AllUrl au = new AllUrl();
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    cr.setUrl(http://zzz.com/api/logins/match? + "username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
 }
```

Comment: Is it due to url? API is in http & I think iOS require https. But if so why is previous version working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to new Apple regulations that prevents apps from fetching data from non secure URL `http`. You can fix this temporarily by adding below build hint:

```
ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict><key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleURLName</key><string>com.mycompany.myapp</string></dict><dict><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array><string>MyApp</string></array></dict></array>
```

Note that your app may be rejected if connected to a non secure URL.

Comment: After I add it in build hint, the app can't be installed in devices. It shows "Unable to download App" dialog box

Comment: That's network related, try deleting old app and restart your device.

Comment: no still the same. I tried by replacing com.mycompany.myapp with my package name but the prob exists

Comment: Also, replace `MyApp` in  `<string>MyApp</string>` with your app name

Comment: Thankyou Diamond. It works in debug mode. If it gets rejected, what are consequences. I can get https latter and still upload in appstore, can't I?

Comment: No consequences other than them asking you to remove that line and use `https` URLs then resubmit. In general, it's advisable to always use encrypted data communication in commercial apps, which I believe is what Apple promoting.